# Postgresql hstore to store and search by numeric data

Tags: postgresql, nosql, hstore

In my actual project I am immersing in a "bigdata" problem. We need store a big database where the read performance is important over the write (data changes are minimal and they are controlled).

There are millions of registers, and each register has a lot of key/value information.

I'm testing noSQL databases and in my investigation I found hstore. I know very good postgresql, but I acknowledge that I did not know this module.

I'm reading about hstore performance and I am impressed, but I have a doubt: It's only possible store text as values, so, **Is search by a numeric value impossible?** Of course, it's necessary keep good performance for reading operations. For example, search registers who values of "X" was greater than "10".

If it is impossible, there are alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: When you say _each register has a lot of key/value_ I think you should not use hstore. What did you try with your data in normalized relational? The alternative to hstore is Redis, or vice-versa.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Each register has between 500 and 1500 attributes and it's not possible know what attributes will be. Moreover, there are difference attributes in each register. KVP model in a relational database is used, but we are looking for a good performance solution. In next months, database will be few millions of registers. We are studying Redis as alternative, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do semantically correct searches of any data type with `hstore` by using casts in your queries, this comes with several costs:

- You can't use the generic GiST indexing for hstore. You must instead create specific indexes on particular hstore keys cast to specific types.
- You're incurring the overhead of casting all the rows each time you process them. This is cheap-ish for something like a text to integer cast, but if you're casting `text` to `numeric` or an array, say ... that's going to hurt.

If your data is almost exclusively free-form key/value, trying to jam it into an RDBMS probably isn't ideal. PostgreSQL 9.4 might do this better with the enhanced JSON support, but it's a bit early to say.

Comment: I read about native JSON integration in postgresql 9.2, but in this benckmark http://thebuild.com/presentations/pg-as-nosql-pgday-fosdem-2013.pdf, the performance is so poor respect hstore when you are searching by an attribute. Do you know if json is better than hstore + cast?

Comment: @angelcervera In 9.2, certainly not. I'm referring to the enhanced json support coming in 9.4. Some of that has landed in 9.3, but not IIRC the path-index support you would need.

Comment: You can also index the integer cast of the hstore value ala:
`CREATE INDEX hstore_idxname_intval ON example USING btree ( ((hstore_data->'idxname')::integer) );`

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to search for numerics if you cast the value:

```
select k -> 'k'
from (values
    ('k => 11'::hstore),
    ('k => 010')
) h(k)
where (k -> 'k')::integer >= 10;
```

Comment: If there is any record where `k->'k'` does not contain a number (like `'k => "abc"'`) postgres will return an error.  Can be solved using `WHERE (k->'k' ~ E'^-?\\\d+?$') AND (k -> 'k')::integer >= 10`